# Getting always true while comparing two year using PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an issue. I am trying to compare current year with one given year using PHP but as per my coding it always returns true to me.I am explaining my code below.

```
$datestr="2020-2029";
$curryear=date("Y");
$yearArr=explode("-",$datestr);
$strYear=strtotime($yearArr[0]);
if($curryear < $strYear){
    $flag=true;
}else{
    $flag=false;
}
echo $flag;
```

Here I need the first year before `-` should be `before year/same year` of current year. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: $strYear=strtotime($yearArr[0]);
Will return timestampe of 2016 which returns 1496261760,and is always greater than 2017.
Use
`$strYear=$yearArr[0];`

Comment: why you want to do strtotime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), because this function return timestamp and you need string of year only. Use this:

```
$datestr="2016-2029";
$curryear=date("Y");
$yearArr=explode("-",$datestr);
$strYear=$yearArr[0];
if($curryear < $strYear){
    $flag=true;
}else{
    $flag=false;
}
echo $flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the year in a 4-digit representation (2016), but you're converting it to seconds since 1970 when using `strtotime()`, which is a much bigger number (`var_dump($strYear);` would show `int(1496254560)`). You simply want to remove that function, otherwise you're comparing `2017 < 1496254560`.

```
$datestr = "2016-2029";
$curryear = date("Y");
$yearArr = explode("-",$datestr);
$strYear = $yearArr[0];
if ($curryear < $strYear) {
    $flag = true;
} else {
    $flag = false;
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/IVJmN)

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

Here the response:

```
php > var_dump(strtotime("2016"));
php shell code:1:
int(1496261760)
```

Using strtotime, a 2016 string is converted to an integer. And your year will be always lower than that number.

PHP auto-cast variables.

```
php > var_dump("2016" < 2015);
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
php > var_dump("2016" < 2018);
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
```

To try this at home, run "php -a" in your bash. You can try php on the fly.